# How to use an SAP ABAP RFC in SAPUI5 without using NetWeaver Gateway?

Tags: sapui5, abap, saprfc

There is an SAP ABAP standard table that I'm trying to access in SAPUI5.
I have created an RFC. How do I use this RFC in SAPUI5 to get the data there without using NetWeaver Gateway?

Comment: Why do you want to do it without using Netweaver Gateway (OData Services)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Veera's answer and think that this is the best way of doing it without the Gateway when your application is deployed on the ABAP system (i.e. in the BSP repository). For completeness sake, I will also describe an alternative way of doing it if you are interested in exposing the application on the HANA Cloud Platform (HCP).

ABAP RFCs can be consumed through the HANA Cloud Connector (HCC) by HCP applications. So, if you would want to put your application in the HCP, then an idea would be to expose the RFC through the HCC, consume it e.g. in a Java application and the expose it to a UI5 app through this Java app (e.g. with a Servlet or a JAX-RS service). You can find an example of such a scenario [in this repository](https://bitbucket.org/serbanpetrescu/epmwebsockets/commits/63df829eb62e0e592905223c04874109567fdb8b#chg-scnEpmWebsockets/src/ws/RFCPoller.java) and [here](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/help/frameset.htm?e184daba118b46679c6968567bacc98e.html) you can find the SAP documentation about this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a rest service or Web Service on the SAP system and consume the URL in your SAPUI5 application. You can create a SICF service and developer a handler for the service. In the handler you can fetch the content from the table and return the content.

Thanks and Regards,
Veera

Answer (score 0):

Another HCP example is [SFlight Sample Application](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/03/04/sflight-sample-showing-how-to-use-jco-and-rfc-to-integrate-with-on-premise-abap-system/).

Open source [python](https://github.com/SAP/PyRFC) and [nodejs](https://github.com/SAP/node-rfc) rfc connectors are also available, if RFC connection required.